# Responsive Website not working on Tablet version

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have a resposive site which works fine on desktop and mobile version but on Tablet version, text and images are not in appropriate places and move towards right side making it non-responsive.

You can check the link here for screenshot:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/835qg39vor9fhe9/websiteresponsive.JPG

This is my website: http://www.sociolife.co.in/

PS: When site is opened at full browser width in desktop, this problem wont occur but when you try to decrease the browser width search bar and subscription box is moving towards right.

Please can you tell me if there is any CSS problem or is there any javascript problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: You'd probably be missing media-queries for the tablet resolution range.

Comment: Sir then what media queries code should I add and where I will add them? Can you please tell me the necessary changes which I have to make in my code and at which places?

Comment: I have answered, please make those changes and let me know! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change in your html file:
At line 1195 of your source code change wiz.

```
#main-nav {
width: 1000px;
}
```

change it to:

```
#main-nav {
width: 103%;
}
```

At line 1201:

```
.column-right-outer{
width:320px;
float:left;
}
```

to the below code:

```
.column-right-outer{
display: none;
}
```

At line 1204 change this:

```
.column-center-outer{
width:670px;
border-right: 0px solid #eaeaea;
}
```

to this:

```
.column-center-outer{
width:620px;
border-right: 0px solid #eaeaea;
}
```

---

edit- 27/04/15
delete the following lines at line 1208:

```
#menu-main {
  display: none;
}
```

**Add the below lines of code in a separate `<style></style>` tag in your HTML file.**

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 730px) and (max-width: 1028px){
            #menu-main {
             margin-top: -10px;
            }

                #main-nav ul li {
                  z-index: 20;
                  text-transform: uppercase;
                  font-family: Oswald,arial,Georgia, serif;
                  font-size: 12px;
                  position: relative;
                  display: inline-block;
                  float: left;
                  border: 1px solid;
                  border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
                  height: 50px;
                }
        }
```

Now your site will look much better. :)

Comment: thanks bro the problem for search bar and subscription and all those elements which were on right gone away. but the problem for news updates and image slider and all other still exists.

Comment: screenshot link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/6ho3tz7ntpwymwd/webproblem-2.JPg

Comment: I have edited the answer, please modify the code and tell me. :)

Comment: bro i have noticed another prob. when its in tablet version the navigation bar is not showing but before editing it was showing. previously, it was like this in tablet view: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/e1ard35770w0rx6/prob2.JPG                 But now navigation is not showing in tablet view: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/866bi2l7oho5w6y/prob1.JPG    Can you please help meto fix this one.

Comment: Actually, none of my code caused that to disappear. Even in maximized view im not able to see it. If i could see alone can i make it appear in tablet view.

Comment: I could see nav bar in tablet view but not the menus.

Comment: Please check and tell me :)

Comment: bro after editing as u said, the navbar is coming out like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/y1idrpz7sluqjr3/snip.JPG

Comment: the navbar with menus should have been like this whose tempate I am using: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/e1ard35770w0rx6/prob2.JPG   You can also check the sample template: http://dynamicmag-sbtemplates.blogspot.in/ this is what I am using in my site. But the menus are not showing like that

Comment: did u add that in a new <style> </style> tag? with @media and all?

Comment: yes bro i added style tag lyk this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ip5bxv11ob53uoi/Capture.JPG

Comment: bro it would be better if i add u in my blogger as admin so u make the necessary changes....

Comment: yea. I'll try my best.

Comment: Bro can i know ur mail id. so i will send u invitation. and thank u very much for helping me out....

Comment: bro this the sample template which I am using: dynamicmag-sbtemplates.blogspot.in  here it is working perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Your meta viewport is wrong. You should use something like this :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You can check out this : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Edit : I thought you meant your website wouldn't work in tablet / mobile view. Looking at the code, the width for #main-nav and probably the other few elements are still fixed at 1000px in the 'tablet view'. I think there's something wrong in your media queries.

Edit 2 : Based on your CSS, here's some relevant code (I'm taking #main-nav as example, you can check for other affected elements) :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1028px){
    #main-nav{
        width:1000px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 725px){
    #main-nav{
        width:430px;
    }
}
```

Do you see the problem now? You're making the navigation 1000px wide for screen sizes between 726px and 1028px. You should have used `width:100%` or `width:725px` for your `#main-nav`'s 'tablet version'. Now you just need to apply the same principle and check for other areas of your website which have the same problem.

Comment: Sir, problem lies in the media queries. He should add media queries for a specific resolution range. There he can give fixed though smaller px.

Comment: Yes, I've realized it after posting the answer and added it to my answer. Nevertheless, he shouldn't have used a fixed width for his meta viewport if he wants it to be responsive.

Comment: Sir which all media queries should I change ? Can you please tell me please here? What all changes I have to make?

Comment: @VelLouise : I've added my 2nd edit to show the problem

Comment: There are too many things which are wrong. You just need to check for each of those elements which are exceeding the width within the media queries for the screen sizes, and their sizes for the corresponding media query. This is not the place for others to do the work for you. You should learn and apply it yourself.

Comment: @Billy Sir I could not understand this line "You should have used width:100% or width:725px for your #main-nav's 'tablet version'." You mean i will change width:430px; to width:100% or any other thing? Can you please explain me

Answer (score 0):

- This works well.

  ```
      @media only screen and (min-width: 730px) and (max-width: 1028px){
       #menu-main {
        margin-top: -10px;
       }

           #main-nav ul li {
             z-index: 20;
             text-transform: uppercase;
             font-family: Oswald,arial,Georgia, serif;
             font-size: 12px;
             position: relative;
             display: inline-block;
             float: left;
             border: 1px solid;
             border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
             height: 50px;
           }
   }
  ```